# keyerror message was given after runing dataframe.head().to_dict()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `season_statistics_T1`,  its related information is given as follows. Each operation looks normal except `season_statistics_T1.head().to_dict()`,  which gives the key error message. I am not sure why.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One thing to try: `season_statistics_T1['season_copy']=[i for i in season_statistics_T1['Season']` then drop the original Season column and see if it throws the same error for the new column

Comment: I got the keyerr 'Season' why trying season_statistics_T1['season_copy']=[i for i in season_statistics_T1['Season']

Comment: Besides, season_statistics_T1.head().to_dict('records') and season_statistics_T1.head().to_dict('split') will work. But to_dict() and to_dict('list') will give keyerror

Answer (score 1):

Lets try

```
df.head().to_json(orient="split")
```

Or

```
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

Comment: I tried  season_statistics_T1.head().to_json(orient=""), it gets error ValueError: Invalid value '' for option 'orient';  setting orient="records" will output information. Please see the update in the original post.

Comment: Me bad.  See edits. Sorry editing from phone.  Let me know if OK.

Comment: Thanks, with these parameter settings. It worked fine. I also tried df.to_dict(). I found that df.to_dict('records') will work just fine, but df.to_dict() and df.to_dict('list') will not work.

Comment: Happy I was of help. Are you able to upvote and accept answer so that others can use your question and my answer with confidence?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. But I still do not know how to solve my questions, i.e., why df.to_dict() gives key error message?